# Getting an element from string array

Tags: android

I want to get an element from string array in android and my string array is:

```
String[] arrayID = {"3740","3491","3661","3838"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can get element by the index...

`arrayID[0]` will give you `3740` and so on...

Or you can loop through and get the elements...

```
for( int i = 0; i < arrayID.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i+" = "+arrayID[i]);
}
```

**Output**
0 = 3740
1 = 3491
2 = 3661
3 = 3838

Answer (score 0):

`String myID = arrayID[0]` to access the first element. Replace `0` with other index numbers to access successive items.

so:

```
String myFirstID = arrayID[0] //returns "3740"
String mySecondID = arrayID[1] //returns "3491"
String myThirdID = arrayID[2] //returns "3661"
String myFourthID = arrayID[3] //returns "3838"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String[] arrayID = {"3740","3491","3661","3838"};
```

you can get element from array by specifying the index of element

where index of first element

3740 is 0,

3491 is 1 and so on

```
arrayId[index]
```